# Why are params arrays and optional parameters not generated by the roslyn SyntaxGenerator?

Tags: .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

The roslyn [SyntaxGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.editing.syntaxgenerator) generates Syntax based on symbols. I've used these APIs quite extensively so far without any problems, but recently I came across one specific case which is not working as expected:

- When using `SyntaxGenerator.MethodDeclaration(IMethodSymbol)`, certain parameter properties are **not** generated properly in the SyntaxNodes although they are present in the orginal symbol. So far this was the case for:

  - **params arrays** (=> instead, an ordinary array parameter is created)
  - **optional parameters** (=> the initializer expression is missing)
- This is true for generated C# code as well as for VB.NET (so regardless of the output language, params arrays and optional parameters are not generated properly).

### Sample code:

```cs
public class GenerationDemo
{
    public static string GenerateMethod()
    {
        using var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
        var project = GetProject(workspace);

        var type = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result?.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeof(GenerationDemo).FullName);
        var method = type.GetMembers(nameof(Test)).Cast<IMethodSymbol>().Single();
        var generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(project);

        return generator.MethodDeclaration(method).NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString();
    }

    public void Test(bool something = true, params int[] numbers)
    {
    }

    private static Project GetProject(AdhocWorkspace workspace)
    {
        const string projectName = "TestProject";
        var projectInfo = ProjectInfo.Create(ProjectId.CreateNewId(), VersionStamp.Create(), projectName,
            projectName, LanguageNames.CSharp,
            metadataReferences: new[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(GenerationDemo).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(string).Assembly.Location)
            });
        return workspace.AddProject(projectInfo);
    }
}
```

#### Expected behaviour:

`GenerationDemo.GenerateMethod()` returns:

```
public void Test(global::System.Boolean something = false, params global::System.Int32[] numbers)
{
}
```

#### Actual behaviour:

`GenerationDemo.GenerateMethod()` returns:

```
public void Test(global::System.Boolean something, global::System.Int32[] numbers)
{
}
```

#### Questions:

- Why are specific pieces like params arrays and optional parameters not generated by the roslyn SyntaxGenerator?
- Is there a way to achieve the desired result with the help of the SyntaxGenerator (besides of just adjusting the generated syntax manually afterwards for the specific cases)
- ...or is this just not supported by the SyntaxGenerator? If so, is this documented somewhere and what else is not generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might just be a bug. I'd recommend filing one on GitHub if you didn't already.